# Spring boot with jersey only as a client

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jersey-client

I uses latest of spring boot and I would like to use jersey as a rest client. But I really do not need a rest server!

Including

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

starts a jersey server.

How can I disable this? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was, adding the following to the `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>    <!-- Spring boot's version -->
    </dependency>
```

and removing the dependency to `spring-boot-starter-jersey`.